# Why am I getting Warning: C4244?

Tags: c++, warnings

So I've been getting: Warning C4244 '=': conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data line 158. From what I understand is that 'pow' and 'long int result' are somehow connected to this, I have been messing around with it and changed 'long int result' to 'double result' and got rid of the warning. I have a solution to get rid of the warning, but it won't matter since this program need long int to handle more data otherwise it will overflow if I use double.

If I decided to keep this warning in the program will there be potenial issues with it?
Can I somehow get rid of the warning and still be able to use 'long int result' or at least be able to handle more data some other way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char menu, choice; 
    int numberYears = 0;
    long int deposit, withdraw;
    long int result = 0;
    long int annualDeposit = 0;
    float interestRate = 0.0;   
    long int balance = 0;
    cout << "------------------------------\n" << "Welcome to Bank Simulator 3000" << "\n------------------------------\n\n"; 

    while (true) 
    {
        cout << "XXXXXXX[MENU]XXXXXXXX\n";
        cout << "[D]eposit\n";
        cout << "[W]ithdrawal\n";
        cout << "[B]alance\n";
        cout << "[I]nterest payment\n";
        cout << "[E]xit\n";
        cout << "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n";
        cin >> menu;



        switch (menu) 
        {
        case'd':
        case'D':
            cout << "\n[DEPOSIT]\n";
            cout << "Do you want to make a deposit?\n" << "Y/N\n";
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') 
            {
                cout << "\nHow much do you want to deposit?\n" << "\n:";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\nReturning to menu.\n\n";
                continue;
            }
            cin >> deposit;
            balance += deposit; 
            cout << "\n" << deposit << " Kr has been added to balance.\n\n";
            continue; 
        case'w':
        case'W':
            cout << "\n[WITHDRAWAL]\n" << "Do you want to make a withdrawal?\n" << "Y/N\n";
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
            {
                cout << "\nHow much do you want to withdraw?\n" << "\n:";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\nReturning to menu.\n\n";
                continue;
            }
            cin >> withdraw;
            if (withdraw == 0)
            {
                cout << "\nYou withdrew 0 amount. No changes will apply.\n\n";
                continue;
            }
            balance -= withdraw; 
            cout << "\n" << withdraw << " Kr has been drawn from balance.\n\n";
            continue;
        case'b':
        case'B':
            cout << "\n[BALANCE]\n";
            cout << balance << " Kr\n\n"; 
            continue;
        case'i':
        case'I':
            cout << "\n[INTEREST PAYMENT]\n";
            cout << "Do you want to calculate your interest payment?\n" << "Y/N\n";
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
            {
                cout << "What's your annual deposit?\n" << ":";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\nReturning to menu.\n\n";
                continue;
            }

            cin >> annualDeposit;
            if (annualDeposit == 0) 
            {
                cout << "You typed 0 in your annual deposits, this will give unwanted results.\n" << "Do you want to continue?\n" << "Y/N\n";
                cin >> choice;
                if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y'); 
                    
                else
                {
                cout << "Returning to menu.\n\n";
                continue;
                }

            }
            cout << "What's Your Interest Rate?\n" << ":";
            cin >> interestRate;
            if (interestRate == 0) 
            {
                cout << "You typed 0 in your interest rate, this will give unwanted results.\n" << "Do you want to continue?\n" << "Y/N\n";
                cin >> choice;
                if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');
                    
                else
                {
                    cout << "Returning to menu.\n\n";
                    continue;
                }

            }
            cout << "How many years do you want to save to?\n" << ":";
            cin >> numberYears;
            if (numberYears <= 0)
            {
                cout << "You typed 0 or less in number of years, this will give unwanted results.\n" << "Do you want to continue?\n" << "Y/N\n";
                cin >> choice;
                if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');
                    
                else
                {
                    cout << "Returning to menu.\n\n";
                    continue;
                }

            }
            result = annualDeposit * pow(1 + interestRate / 100, numberYears); 
            cout << "Your Interest Payment Will Be: " << result << " Kr In " << numberYears << " Years\n\n";
            continue;


        default:
            cout << "\nPlease use the following example\n" << "D = Deposit | W = Withdrawal | B = Balance | I = Interest payment | E = Exit\n\n";
            continue;

        case'e':
        case'E':
            cout << "Thanks for using Bank Simulator 3000!\n";
            cout << "Press any key to close";
            system("pause>0");
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: All variants of `pow()` from `<cmath>` return a floating point type (`float`, `double`, etc).    Floating point variables cannot necessarily represent every integral value e.g. a `float` is typically 32-bits, and can represent a much larger range of values than a 32-bit integral type - which means it cannot represent every value a 32-bit integer can. Converting a floating point value to a integral type therefore introduces error or loses data, and your compiler is warning about that. To fix, work out a way to raise an integral value to an integral power without using floating point functions.

Answer (score 1):

In typical environment, a `double` variable can store a floating-point number upto about `10^300` (assuming IEEE754 64-bit is used).

On the other hand, a `long int` can store an integer only upto about `10^9` (32-bit) or `10^18` (64-bit).

Therefore, the maximum value to handle by `long int` is much smaller than one for `double`. This is why conversion from `double` to `long int` can cause loss of data.

You can add an explicit cast to suppress the warning.

```cpp
result = static_cast<long int>(annualDeposit * pow(1 + interestRate / 100, numberYears));
```

Comment: The `static_cast` will shut the compiler up.   It doesn't address the cause of the problem though - which is that converting a `double` to a `long int` loses precision and introduces error in its own right.